# get execution income in beaconcha API

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, staking

I want to query the execution of the public key: 0xaf93696b857fb621048539d0f9ee7722d801e05cf3be3039decd17b937dd9d69f4450c407f5ae4e96d875cb754840c1c

Request interface <https://beaconcha.in/api/v1/validator/0xaf93696B857FB621048539D0F9EE77722D805CF3Be3039DECD17B937F4450C407F5AE9E9 6D875CB7548 40C1C/Executive/Performance>

The results obtained:
{
"status": "OK",
"data": []
}

But
I request in browser: <https://beaconcha.in/validator/af93696b857fb621048539d0f9ee7722d801e05cf3be3039decd17b937dd9d69f4450c407f5ae4e96d875cb7548 40c1c>
The page shows that the execution income is 0.17608ETH.

What should I do to get the correct execution reward via API?

I tried to get the correct execution reward, but when the result was [], the API did not return the correct result. Am I using the wrong interface?